# how 3.2<= pick the right layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

beginning from 3.2, you can specify layout with layout-sw600p for example.
Now, if i specify both, say layout-ldpi/mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi and layout-sw600p, how 3.2 and later (such as 4.0) handle which layout to use ?
will it choose layout-xhdpi or layout-sw600p ?

I cannot test it by my own. Since my phone is still using 2.3.

Answer (score 3):

If it follows the rules, `layout-sw600p` should be considered before `layout-xlarge` (note: `-xhdpi` is for density, which has nothing to do with size and usually is not used for layouts). `-swNNNdp` is higher in "Table 2" in the [Android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources), which means it is a more important qualifier, which means it should be considered first.

> I cannot test it by my own. Since my phone is still using 2.3.

Then test it on an emulator. Do not use resource set qualifiers that you do not test.